How do I export Splash Screen from Android Studio to the App on Google Play Store?
I'm a first time user of android apps development, and  I'm stuck with an issue related to a splash screen. I got this warning:
"The crawler detected a blank loading screen or a custom splash screen that is shown in your app after the system splash screen. Users launching your app on Android 12 or higher will see 2 splash screens. To fix this issue, update your app to use the SplashScreen API."
My problem is that I can't find a place in Google Console to setup the Splash Screen API. I downloaded Android Studio and I created a a splash screen, but I can't find there either where to link/upload it into my app in google Console. I followed the links that came with the warning but can't find it.
I opened a ticket with Google and Also Android Studio and they both referred mee to each other saying they don't do technical help.
Any advice will be appreciated Sincerely,
Mario T
I have created the Splashscreen on Android Studio. I just don't know how to send it to google PLay console, where my app resides.
